# IFrame Resize Solution - A Cross-Browser Compatible Solution

Tags: php, javascript, html

New Year Greetings Y'all....

I know there are some references to this issue here on stackoverflow, but I found none of them quite useful. I've an Iframe whose src attribute is dynamically set through PHP. I would like it to resize itself according to it's content ( JavaScript) . Any insights?

(Solutions mentioned on this site for the same problem faced do not work for me)

Thank You,
Abhijit

Comment: Content from same origin (host, port, protocol)?

Answer (score 1):

Best solution: Don't use an IFrame, but embed the content inside a div. That will give you much more control. An IFrame is more or less a black box. I don't think the document outside the box can not what is in the box (for security reasons), so it cannot perform calculations either. The document inside the box doesn't even know that it's inside an IFrame.

The best option would be to let the PHP document determine which page is shown, but do that a little earlier, so you can use that fact to render a slight difference in the parent document as well.

Comment: Too many "think" in your post. If the content is from the same origin, both parent and child can access each other. And how would PHP know how high the document will render in the browser???

Comment: Apparently PHP is the one that determines the src of the IFrame, so it would seem appropriate if at that point a different layout is chosen as well. I'm not sure if an exact pixel height is needed. If so, the src wouldn't even matter, because one source can render differently in different browsers. I assumed just a generally different layout based on the global contents of the IFrame.